# Installation failed with message Failed to create install session with 'cmd package install-create -r -t -S 1647504'

Tags: android-studio, failed-installation

I am getting an error message while trying to run an apk through android studio 3.4.1

Installation failed with message Failed to create install session with 'cmd package install-create -r -t -S 1647504'.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

i have tried cleaning the project, rebuilding the project and unchecking the instant run option as well, none of them seems to have worked

Comment: Have you trued uninstalling the APK and reinstalling?

Comment: yes i did, did not work

Answer (score 15):

The below is the solution that worked for me:

1. In Android Studio go to **Tools** -> **AVD Manager**.
2. Choose a device, you are trying to deploy APK on, expand actions with a down-facing triangle and wipe data from Emulator.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same message while there is a physical device connected to my Android studio, when I check the logs then I got to know that it was due to my **phone's full memory**.Once I **deleted** some stuff I was able to install the app properly.

Comment: Thats my problem too

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by "wipe data".
for fix this problem go to AVD manager and select your Simulator and then select "wipe data" from dropdown menu

Answer (score -1):

It's been a year but I just had the same issue and I found this other solution that works for me: [Source to solution with images](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_32143399/article/details/100142770)

1. Click on the arrow at the right of where it says app in the center top of the screen
2. Click on edit configurations
3. In the bottom part of the new window, click the + icon where it says "Before launch: Gradle-aware Make" and select the option "Gradle-aware Make"
4. In the pop up window write :app:installDebug and click OK
5. Click OK again in the previous window and try to install the app, I hope it works