# Unrelated app name showing on execution of Android apps - gradle error?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio and I don't know all the ins and out of the build process yet. All my projects were working fine until recently, when it seems that something happened (maybe I touched something unwittingly?) and now even new, fresh projects with a mere `onCreate()`  don´t work. Not even the fresh ones with the `helloworld` tag, so it's not to do with the code. I was checking the logcat and they all show the following on execution:

```
2020-12-16 10:26:39.543 28376-28376/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: grass.mary.newApp, PID: 28376
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{grass.mary.newApp/grass.mary.newApp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: ScrollView can host only one direct child
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
```

followed by:

```
   --------- beginning of system
2021-01-09 12:21:49.819 22348-13682/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-01-09 12:22:34.847 1656-1662/? E/zygote: Timed out waiting for threads to suspend, waited for 10.000s
```

And perhaps more tellingly, on the Run tab it says in red:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\test\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'Failed to create install session with 'cmd package install-create -r -t -S 1749180''
Retry
```

I find strange that it says `Process: grass.mary.newApp, PID: 28376` because 'newApp' is not the app that I'm currently running. And this happens with all other projects that used to work fine, they all display the exact same error on execution with the line `Process: grass.mary.newApp, PID: 28376`  which references an App that is totally unrelated to the one I'm executing (I did create this 'newApp' in the past and it's in the projects folder).

Any ideas of what the issue might be?

Comment: Just put your layout that's inside <ScrollView> in one Layout like RelativeLayout or LinearLayout. That way you have <ScrollView><LinearLayout><YourViews>...</YourViews></LinearLayout></ScrollView>. This is because ScrollView can host only one child View.

Answer (score 2):

The line

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

in the stack trace gives a hint that in the application of package `grass.mary.newApp` you are using a `ScrollView` with more than one child.

Remember that according to [the docs of `ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView):

> ... Scroll view may have only one direct child placed within it. ...

To sovle this, you may put all your children into a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and then put the `LinearLayout` into the `ScrollView`.

Also note that you should take care of your application's package name inside the manifest file. According to [the App Manifest Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#package-name):

> ... once the APK is compiled, the package attribute also represents your app's universally unique application ID.

And, as far as I know, the package name in the manifest should be the same with the Gradle's `gradle.build` module file (in the constant named `applicationId`). You may read [the corresponding page on changing the id](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#change_the_package_name) for more information.

Another thing to note is that, in Android, you are not only using the Java/Kotlin coded files, but also numerous XML files such as those under the `res` directory of your project. In your case, if you are just setting the content view with `setContentView` in your main entry point's `Activity` and you are using a layout from the `R` class to set it, then the problem with the `ScrollView` may rely on the fact that the corresponding layout (such as for example `res/layout/activity_main.xml`) uses a `ScrollView` with multiple elements (instead of only one) and that's probably why you are seeing this exception.

---

### Edit 1:

Now you have updated your question, seems like the problem may be relevant to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374314/installation-failed-with-message-failed-to-create-install-session-with-cmd-pack) other question. Can you check it out and tell us if the given answers on that post solved the problem?

Basically what they suggest is that maybe you did not allocate enough RAM and/or space for your emulated device (ie the device has already many applications in it and cannot install more, unless you wipe the data or increase the space or uninstall some stuff first).

If that doesn't work, the other suggested solution on that post is that you should edit the installation configurations. Be aware here that they are talking about Android Studio version 3.5.

Comment: but grass.mary.newApp is NOT the app I am executing, as I explained in my question. The fresh apps have nothing on it and definitely have no ScrollView's. It seems that in the build something is referencing an an app folder that should not be referenced.

Comment: I updated my answer. How do you know that `grass.mary.newApp` is not your application's package? I am asking this because if you have overriden the attribute `package` of the `manifest` XML element in the manifest file, then you are probably forgetting that Gradle will override this.

Comment: because when I create a new empty app with the name TEST, for example, and run it, the error message comes up referencing that `grass.mary.newApp` and complains about a ScrollView that does not even exist in the newly created TEST app. Furthermore, in the `manifest` the package attribute is `grass.mary.test` as expected. I added what the Run tab returns after stoping app execution, if helps. thanks

Comment: What is the value of `applicationId` in the `build.gradle` module file? Are you running this on an emulated device or a physical one?

Comment: value of applicationId on `build.gradle` is `grass.mary.test`. I am running this on an emulated device.

Comment: I edited my answer too. Look at the **Edit 1** paragraphs. What is your Android Studio version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227084/discussion-between-gthanop-and-mary-grass).